# I can pick thing up but I can’t see where it is in my inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There is no inventory on the game I have tried to change the view to see if it would help but it did not.

[image]

Comment: As in your hotbar has disappeared? You should be able to access you inventory by pressing E (or check the controls in the options menu). If your hotbar is gone, try... F1 I think?

Comment: Please don't make a photo of your screen. Press F2 instead.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Unionhawk.  I suspect you have [toggled](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Heads-up_display#Options) the [heads-up display](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Heads-up_display).  Press <kbd>F1</kbd> to toggle it again.  Usually this is used to turn the display off so that screen shots can be taken without the display.